# html select list onchange failed to call method on Google Chrome (Works for IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have a `select` list and `options` are populated from database as below:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser()">
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';   
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT userName FROM user';

mysql_select_db('finance');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $val = $row['ID'];
    echo "<option value=$val>" . $row['userName'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

And this is the very simple alert function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser()
{
    alert("haha");
}
</script>
```

I do able to get the values from database but whenever onChange, there are no alert?

**EDIT**:

It WORKS on IE but not Google Chrome?!

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, see what happens when you change items in the select.

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: pree ctrl + f5  i think due to cache problems occurs

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I'm using Google Chrome and the console I only see `GET http://ads.okitspace.com/uploads/cover.js?id=18adcbe810cba5740f2e36a786828a3c&affid=SOFTPLUS`

Comment: @Riturajratan: I've tried that, still remain the same

Comment: May be a far shot but: `value=$val` should be `value='$val'`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).find(':selected').val();
})
```

Comment: Remain the same, failed to trigger the method

Comment: BTW: `this.value` won't work. It's `$(this).find(':selected').val()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid using inline JS. So, remove the `onchange` event in your `<select>` element:

```
<select name="users">...</select>
```

And instead, rely on using event handlers provided by jQuery to do so:

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name='users']").change(function() {
        alert("onchange() event detected");
    });
});
```

If your `<select>` element is dynamically added though, you might want to use the `.on()` method for event binding:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("change", "select[name='users']", function() {
        // Rest of the code
    });
});
```

On a side note, it is probably not a good idea to use `mysql_` functions anymore — try looking into migrating over to either `mysqli_` or PDO.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/K2GMx/

Comment: By using your way, I cant even `alert` on IE, it's actually getting worse

Comment: Nope, seems to work perfectly on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/K2GMx/). I'm using Chrome. What version of IE are you using? Did you load jQuery, and is it loaded properly? If the Fiddle works for you, it means that something is wrong, or interfering, in your own example.

Comment: Now it works for IE, but the problem remains on Google Chrome. When it works on IE I assume the jQuery successfully being loaded? But not googleChrome?

Comment: Not possible. I am using Chrome, and the Fiddle works just fine. Did you check the console log? Does it throw any errors?

Answer (score 0):

you should place your js function before your select:

```
<script>
function showUser()
{
    alert("haha");
}
</script>

<select name="users" onChange="showUser();">
<option value=sdf>sdfs</option>
<option value=s1df>sdf1s</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xd8b6/

or place your function in the `<head>` of a document

Comment: The `script` is in the `<head>` section, as mentioned, it works on IE but not Chrome

Comment: @IsaacLem look at my fiddle in your chrome - does it work? what Chrome version you using?

Comment: Yes, your fiddle is working fine. But not for my piece of code? Meaning the method cant be invoke if the options are populated from database? Only for Chrome? Btw my chrome version : Version 30.0.1599.69 m

Comment: @IsaacLem yes same as mine... well you either have broken code somewhere else on the html/js or you need to go to Chrome settings -> Show advanced settings -> Clear browsing data -> select: Delete cookies and oth.. + Empty the cache